# how can i use IF commands to show different information on a table?

Tags: php, html

i am trying to show information using IF/ELSEIF commands

i have A through Z along the top of the page and want to show a table with all results starting with each letter

for example i have

```html
<a href='?a'>A</a>
```

```html
<?php

if($_GET == a)
{
  echo "<table><tr><th>[picture]</th><th>information</th></tr>";
} 
?>
```

i want to show a table with all the information, how would i do this using IF/ELSE commands? is there a better way of doing this without going to a different page?

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Hi, assassin, and welcome to StackOverflow. Can you show your try? And add more details. Please also read  careful “[How do ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be easier/cleaner to use a switch-case instead of if-else for your purpose here.

First off, try changing the links to something like this:

```
<a href='?l=a'>A</a>
```

and

```
<a href='?l=b'>B</a>
```

Then you should try to access the chosen letter with something like this:

```
<?php
$sLetter = null;
if (isset($_GET['l'])) {
    $sLetter = strtolower($_GET['l']);
}
switch ($sLetter) {
    case 'a':
        echo "Information related to A";
        break;
    case 'b':
        echo "Information related to B";
        break;
    // Continue in a similar way for the remaining letters
    default:
        echo "No information..."; // or perhaps show all A-Z information
        break;
}
```

Note: For testing purposes, this is okay. But [Superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) should always be validated and sanitised to make your application more secure.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for the reply, i tried this though and it just shows everything on the page even the <?php tags which is a bit strange, any idea whats causing this

Comment: i do apologize, it seems to have worked once i uploaded the files to my host, thank you very much